Extracting frequencies from a 2D image, what is the sampling frequency?
I have a set of images that are effectively different types of banded animal patterns. I would like to be able to compare them in the frequency domain. My intention is to extract the frequencies that make up the banded patterns after running through DFT. In order to know what frequencies are associated with what frequency bins, I believe you would use the formula $\frac{n * f_s}{N}$, where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency, n is the bin index, and N is the width of the image (in pixels). I understand how to get $n$ and $N$, but I do not understand how to get $f_s$. What is the sampling frequency for a 2D image taken on a regular digital camera? Is this the number of pixels per unit distance in real life?

It's complicated, and subject to what's the most important to the problem at hand.
I'm going to give you examples of what I have used.  I'm going to be lazy here and assume a square image -- your aspect ratio is probably not square; it's up to you to extend this reasoning to $N \times M$ images.
Your choices if you know nothing about the camera are:

$f_s = \frac 1 {\mathrm{frame}}$, and the frequencies are in cycles per frame.
$f_s = \frac N {\mathrm{pixel}}$, and the frequencies are in cycles per pixel.

If you know the camera's field of view (and if the image is reasonably undistorted) then $$f_s = \frac N {\theta_{FOV}}$$ where $\theta_{FOV}$ is the field of view of the camera.
If you know the camera's field of view and the range to the animal -- or if you can otherwise come up with a reference to pixels per length -- then $$f_s = \frac N l$$, where $l$ is the field of view, in meters, at the range to your animal.
The measure that would be easiest to use if you knew it, and hardest to know, is the last one.
